# Why CSS isn't working on innerHTML in Pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm creating a Pop-up using vanilla JavaScript. To inject the HTML I'm using innerHTML. If I try to get the style of the content of the Pop-up, it's giving me a blank text. Why??

**Edited :**

```
...
<div class="content" id="msg${this.id}">
        
    </div>
  </div>`;
body.innerHTML = popup;
}

minimize() {
let display = this.content.style.display;
console.log(display);
display = display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

Comment: You didn't show how `this.content` is set. I assume that node simply doesn't have any inline `display` style set (maybe it comes from a stylesheet instead). Are you maybe looking for [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) instead?

Comment: Please don't post code as an image.

Comment: @CherryDT , this.content = document.getElementById(`msg${id}`); yes, it doesn't have inline CSS.

Comment: `this.content.style.display` is giving an empty string because is it `unset` (means the value of this property is not defined by the coder)

Comment: @trincot I didn't know image doesn't work. I'll remember

Comment: SO you need to add its CSS in your CSS file or using js

Comment: @AdibRahman Then it is as I said. You don't have an inline style attribute (`<div style="display: flex;">`) for example, so it is empty. To know what _computed_ style is applied (including all sources of styles, not just the attribute), you need `getComputedStyle`.